# Navigation Bar, not displaying on second ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a navigation controller. I added a plus button to the top right of the navigation controller which opens up a new view controller. However, I want the navigation bar to show up on the new screen as well. But it's not showing. What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing? Here is my code:

`ViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var toDoListTextView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //Setting the Title for the nav bar
        title = "To Do List"
        configureNavigationItems()
    }
    
    private func configureNavigationItems(){
        
        /* Adding a button on the top right of the screen
         * in the navigation bar/controller.
         */
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            barButtonSystemItem: .add,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(didTapPlus)
        )
        
    }
    
    @objc func didTapPlus(){
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "makeTask") as! makeTaskViewController
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        
        vc.title = "Create a Task"
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .black
        
        vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Back",
            style: .done,
            target: self,
            action: nil)
        
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

`Storyboard`

[Click Here To See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggh2a.png)

`Demo of App`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8tI1.gif)

Comment: `navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Is there a way to present it modally?

Comment: @navsharma you'll need to make a new navigation controller for the modal

Comment: @aheze can you please explain? I am really new to this stuff. I am sorry if it's annoying.

Comment: https://github.com/russell-archer/ModalStylesDemo

Comment: @navsharma np. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each modally-presented view controller gets a brand-new view hierarchy. This means that if you want your `MakeTaskViewController` to have a navigation bar, you'll need to manually add a navigation controller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // ... your code ...
    
    @objc func didTapPlus() {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "makeTask") as! MakeTaskViewController
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        
        vc.title = "Create a Task"
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .black
        
        vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Back",
            style: .done,
            target: vc, /// make sure to set `target` as the new view controller
            action: #selector(vc.dismissMe))
        
        /// wrap the new view controller in a navigation controller (this adds the top bar)
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        
        /// so you can actually see the `Create a Task` text,
        navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        
        present(navigationController, animated: true)
    }
    
}

/// side note: `MakeTaskViewController` and other classes should be Capitalized
class MakeTaskViewController: UIViewController {
    @objc func dismissMe() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Newly-presented view controller gets a navigation bar]

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var toDoListTextView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        //Setting the Title for the nav bar
        title = "To Do List"
        configureNavigationItems()
    }

    private func configureNavigationItems(){

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            barButtonSystemItem: .add,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(didTapPlus)
        )
    
    }

@objc func didTapPlus(){
    
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "makeTask") as! makeTaskViewController
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    
    vc.title = "Create a Task"
    vc.view.backgroundColor = .black
    
    vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: "Back",
        style: .done,
        target: self,
        action: nil)
    
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    //present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```